# Django - Parse JSONP (Json with Padding)

Tags: python, django, jsonp

I'm using **JSONP** to send data from `otherdomain.com` to `mydomain.com`

However, I got errer when I tried to **parse JSONP data in django controller** (`views.py`).

Here is my code.

---

Javascript in `mydomain.com` client page

```
jsonData = {
    'foo': 'bar',
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://otherdomain.com/end_point/',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: jsonData,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonp : 'callback'
});
```

---

Django controller (`views.py`) in `mydomain.com`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def decode_jsonp(request):

    if 'callback' in request.GET:
        json_object = json.loads(request.body) # Raise error
        json_object = json.dumps(request.body) # Do not raise error but returns nothing
        json_object = json.loads(json.dumps(request.body)) # Raise error

        foo = json_object['foo']

    return JsonResponse({'foo': foo})
```

I don't know what should I substitue for `json_object = json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I got 500 internal server error at client page, but its response is empty. I run django with debug mode. I cannot find error in uWSGI log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JSONP object has parentheses around it and a callback. But Python's `json` module doesn't recognise a JSONP object. So, you'll have to first convert it to JSON object by removing the surrounding parentheses and the callback name.

Example

```
>>> data = 'callback({"key": "val"})' # a common JSONP object
>>>
>>> json.loads(data)
# raises ValueError
>>>
>>> data_json = data.split("(", 1)[1].strip(")") # convert to json
>>> data_json
'{"key": "val"}' 
>>>
>>> json.loads(data_json)
# success
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was key to solve my problem. I posted solution below.

Comment: If you have `(` in your json, the result is wrong. You should use `data.split("(", 1)`.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for pointing that out. I've updating the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @xyres. Here is solution.

```
def decode_jsonp(request):

    if 'callback' in request.GET:
        query_string = request.GET.urlencode()
        json_object = {x.split('=')[0]:str(x.split('=')[1]) for x in query_string.split("&")}

        foo = json_object['foo']

    return JsonResponse({'foo': foo})
```