# How to convert this large json file into a Python object?

Tags: javascript, python

I have this JSON file which contains the data in an interactive map displaying UK food banks run by The Trussell Trust.

[food bank data](https://www.trusselltrust.org/get-help/find-a-foodbank/foodbank-search/?foodbank_s=all&callback=?)

I am trying to use `json.loads()` and I keep getting a syntax error. I think Python may be confusing `'` with `"` because every time there's a word like `there's` it interprets the ``' as the end of a string.

Basically I need to convert the data in that link into any python object.

Edit: fixed the link. Is it possible to get that data and work with it in python or do I need to learn JS?

Comment: The data in that link seems to be some javascript code

Comment: The link you have posted does not contain a JSON response, but consists of JavaScript code instead

Comment: The provided link shows `if (console) { console.log("error - no callback provided for search"); }`, which is javascript, not JSON.

Comment: @jfaccioni: fixed the link btw.

Comment: The link returns 'invalid' JSON (starting with `?(`); looks like JSONP, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import urllib.request, json
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.trusselltrust.org/get-help/find-a-foodbank/foodbank-search/?foodbank_s=all&callback=?") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode()[2:-2])
    print(data[0]['foodbank_information']) # example print
```

The format seems to be `JSONP` (`JSON with padding`). `json` from python does not seem to support this format. If your link changes, especially the `callback=?` argument, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554522/django-parse-jsonp-json-with-padding).

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you could explain what you did?

Comment: Just a detail to point out: even though the code works, it shouldn't rely on assuming that it will always work as it is (with the slice before returning the final json); if the response changes, the code might break; for instance, if someone decides to call this link, the above code will break: https://www.trusselltrust.org/get-help/find-a-foodbank/foodbank-search/?foodbank_s=all&callback=asd

Comment: @Luca the only real difference to normal JSON loading is the slice in the 3rd line `[2:-2]`. Basically it's cutting 2 characters from the beginning and the end wich made the JSON invalid (@Jose Ramirez mentioned that it could be JSONP). A better solution would probably finding a way to read this exact format. I'll see if i can find anything to archieve this.

Comment: @JoseRamirez what do you mean by calling a link?

Comment: @JoseRamirez changed `&callback=?` to `&callback=asd` which made the response start with `asd([{"foodbank_information":{"na...` instead of `?([{"foodbank_information":{"na...`. As there are now 4 characters `asd(` before the real JSON instead of 2 `?(`, the string gets sliced incorectly. If you can ensure that `callback` is always a single character, you should be fine.